# XLIFF editor for Windows

Tags: windows, localization

I have an XLIFF file (localization format used by [XCode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) for an iPhone app).

I want to edit this XLIFF file on Windows. Which editor can I use?

Requirements:

- Ability to translate labels of the app, which are short sentences
- Runs on Windows 7 and higher
- As cheap as possible, ideally free and open-source
- Usuable for a beginner, intuitive
- As visual as possible, but still efficient

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Do you have any specific requirements for the software? Currently any XLIFF compatible translation software for windows would match with is very broad. So, could you specify what your translators are going to be working at? Long paragraphs are different to formatted text or single words. Different tools excel at different tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the [PhraseApp](http://phraseapp.com/) which we decided to use. This actually give us more than we asked for. It is a web app that also gives use the opportunity to export in all kinds of formats. It is a service that has a monthly fee.

My project manager is happy. I have a tool that both me a the translators seems to be happy with. Mission accomplished.

Comment: You asked for a Windows tool though... this is a webapp

Comment: This has become rather strange, especially since that latest edit of the question ;-) As per the original question the goal for me and my project manager was to solve our problems, that is the get a translator using windows to be able to translate on her windows machine. Support for being able to do this for Android was a nice extra feature.

The PhraseApp has actually solved our problem. It has given our translator using Windows the ability solve her need. The Android developers, as well as the project managers are happy. So for me the original problem has been solved.

Comment: So given the all new question, this is not an acceptable answer. I do not know why the original background story has been deleted. For me a background story gives the reader the possibility to easier understand what I am looking for.

Comment: I am glad you found a solution :-) As you saw, the question has been put on hold as too broad, that's why I tried to save it by making it more succinct with a list of clear requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Professional translators use professional translation software like SDL Trados Studio, memoQ or Wordfast to translate. All these tools support XLIFF out of the box.

If you want something open-source, you could have a go at Virtaal.

Comment: I tried Virtaal, but it crashed every time at startup.